# moving BigQuery data in the new European zone

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Following the announcement of Google that BigQuery data can now be located in Europe, I'm trying to find out how to start the migration process.
The support has replied to me: "For more information about moving data in the new European zone you will need to contact the Google Cloud Platform technical support team. I invite you to submit your technical questions on Stackoverflow:"

So here I am. How do we move our data to Europe ?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards,
Alain

Comment: As you are instructed you need to contact GCP support team.

Comment: A request to move your data to a different zone shouldn't be submitted via StackOverflow. Who exactly gave you those instructions?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa could you blog about this, and explain what are the steps. I'm interested too.

Comment: @Pentium10 - what questions would you need answered? As it's just launched, it's still a manual process ran by support.

Comment: @FelippeHoffa my boss would like to officially know where data is located, can we see on interface or, who can provide in writing the US/EU zone. Also some do not pay for premium support so where we initiate a new case as the button is disabled: http://screencast.com/t/lfNuDFGe (only enabled when you pay additional amounts for Silver/Bronze etc. packages). How long does the move takes? Is there a down time involved or not? Is it free or not to move data to EU? Are there EU only API points available, as streaming data still goes to US IPs etc...- data  should not go through US endpoints.

Comment: @Pentium10 all fair questions! We are in the process of documenting these details, and we'll make sure to have answers to these (as well as eventually a process that won't require going through support).

Comment: It is too weird that they invited you to submit your technical questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BQ web UI to either:

- Copy the table into a new dataset
- Share the existing dataset
- Export and save the table locally, upload again to new dataset.